# Javascript Module Pattern returning initial value of Private property

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm trying to get a private property from a Module but I always get the initial value of it and not the most recent one.

When the form is submited and onSuccess get called, I set the partnerId = 10.

After that, I have a click event that gets the partner's Id, and get -1

#### search.js

```
var SearchForm = (function ($) {
    "use strict";
    // Private variables
    // Private functions
    var onSuccess = function () {
        PartnerDetail.setPartnerId(10);
    };
    // Public functions
    return {
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
    };
})(jQuery);
```

#### detail.js

```
var PartnerDetail = (function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var _partnerId = -1;
    var getPartnerId = function () {
        return _partnerId;
    };
    var setPartnerId = function (id) {
        _partnerId = id;
    }
    // Public functions
    return {
        getPartnerId: getPartnerId,
        setPartnerId: setPartnerId
    };
})(jQuery);
```

#### search.internal.js

```
var SearchAll = (function ($) {
    "use strict";
    // Private variables
    // Private functions
    var init = function () {
        $("#partner").on("click", function () {
            var p = PartnerDetail.getPartnerId();
            console.log(p); ==> -1
        }
    };
    // Public functions
    return {
        init: init
    };
})(jQuery);
```

#### (main page)

```
// Load when ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    SearchAll.init();
});
```

Comment: seems you have to use a closure function

Comment: Unable to reproduce; works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/or315y60/

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Hi, what do you mean by that?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/7qecxrau/)

Comment: Cache the value, like this: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/ or, better, here: http://lucybain.com/blog/2014/closures/ But, your code seems to use it already, and it works ok.

Comment: You probably have a typo in your assignment

Comment: @Bergi Hi, what do you mean by that?

Comment: the closure you are using is     "var getPartnerId = function () {
        return _partnerId;
    };"

Comment: It seems that it's creating a new PartnerDetail object everytime I call it, and how do I get the actual value?

Comment: I typed your code in DevTools console and it works just fine. What envrionment are you working in? Browser? Which one? Node.js?

Comment: Hi, can you try to access it from another js file?

Comment: Minor addition, you write private & public function, a function is only private as long as you dont return it.

Comment: @Patrick when you call `SearchForm.OnSuccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok:

I have put the following code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfafLyht/1/) and it logs 10:

HTML:

```
<button id="partner">CLICK!</button>
```

JS:

```
var PartnerDetail = (function () {
    var _partnerId = -1;
    var getPartnerId = function () {
        return _partnerId;
    };

    var load = function (id) {
        _partnerId = id;
    }

    // Public functions
    return {
        getPartnerId: getPartnerId,
        load: load
    };
})();

// File search.js

var SearchForm = (function ($) {

    "use strict";

    // Private variables

    // Private functions

    var onSuccess = function () {

        PartnerDetail.load(10);
    };

    // Public functions
    return {

        onSuccess: onSuccess,
    };

})(jQuery);


var SearchAll = (function ($) {

    "use strict";

    // Private variables

    // Private functions
    var init = function () {

        $("#partner").on("click", function () {

            var p = PartnerDetail.getPartnerId();

            console.log(p);
        });

    };

    // Public functions
    return {

        init: init
    };

})(jQuery);

// Load when ready
$(document).ready(function () {

    SearchAll.init();
    SearchForm.onSuccess();
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you try to access it from another js file in another Pattern Module?

Comment: @Patrick I am afraid you will have to share some more details: can you add the code  from your other module in your original request?

Comment: @Patrick I have updated my jsfiddle. it still logs 10 (I have fixed a couple of typos, you might want to  check those. In particular, `setPartnerId` in your code  was undefined and you never invoke `onSuccess`)

Comment: Did you tried diferent files? onSuccess is called by the form after submit

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick - your code is good, except for two tiny mistakes. You need to comment out the `==> -1`, and close the bracket on the following line. Also, you haven't included the code regarding the form, and it's behaviour (i.e. invoking `onSuccess`). Also, you haven't specified which browser you're using.

i.e.

```js
    console.log(p); ==> -1
}
```

should be

```js
    console.log(p); // ==> -1
});
```

#### Solution:

[Here's an example of it working in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tiwexi/5/edit?html,js,console,output)

- you mentioned `onSuccess` is called when a form is submitted, but you haven't included this code in your example. So I took the liberty of adding it to my example.
- logs `-1` before form is submitted, `10` after
- tested in Opera 25
- uses separate js files (as requested)

Below is a code snippet, also demonstrating the behaviour (**N.B.** it's a little slow to load).

```js
// Load when ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    SearchAll.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nickgrealy/bc1f5452cff303348fe7/raw/53c9248298268cea69a49e24895cdc59f9b7da82/detail.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nickgrealy/bc1f5452cff303348fe7/raw/b2cd08800fcec69195e85efd508015c699a4926d/search.internal.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nickgrealy/bc1f5452cff303348fe7/raw/dfb8296180dc3f3302f4a9175c6961b8089fb947/search.js"></script>

<form target="#" onsubmit="SearchForm.onSuccess();return false;">
    <input type="Submit" value="1. Form Submit" />
</form>
<input id="partner" type="button" value="2. Log partnerId"></button>
```

For reference, here are the [js file's source code](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/bc1f5452cff303348fe7) in gist.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have to be doing something wrong but I can't find what is it...it seems that everytime I call "PartnerDetail.getPartnerId" it uses the Module has if it was in his initial value with -1

Comment: @Patrick, try and distill the code down to the bare minimum to reproduce the issue, and then share that (ALL the code) with us (try creating a http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net !). Also, tell us everything. e.g. What browser are you using? What system are you running on? Are you using a webserver, or are you just using the files locally? It's hard for us to diagnose the issue, if we don't have all the information available and can't reproduce the issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this has something to do with the execution time of your events.
Your `onSucess` function is called when you submit your form, isn't it?
But your `onClick` function is executed straight away. Therefore your variable will always have the initial property of -1 within the `onClick` event, because the `onSucess` has not been called at the moment of the `onClick`
Here a little table to elaborate my thoughts on your events a little bit more:

```
onclick, value = -1
onclick, value = -1          value=10
onclick, value = -1          value=10
value=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you get your `PartnerDetail.getPartnerId();`, set it's value.

```
PartnerDetail.setPartnerId(10);
var p = PartnerDetail.getPartnerId();
console.log(p) // 10
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/zLexLvza/1/

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it. You have saved your functions in different files. Each file will maintain its own private state. You will need to combine your code segments into one file or implement a load pattern that will grant access to the private state of the other files.

[See details about the module pattern to share private state between files](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)